# Easy send Ether to multi address?

Tags: ether

How to tranfer ether to 100 address easy?
Im try ing wallet contract and multisend ETH with myetherwallet.com but not working.Ether tran to Wallet contract but not send to other address.

Other method tranfer ether to multi address easy to beginer?

Answer (score 2):

This contract will do what you need.

This implies that when deploying it you should send the ether, that is why the constructor is payable. You can also just deploy it and then send the ether to the contract. See that that the address used to deploy the contract is also the owner. Only the owner will be able to execute the function to send the transactions, also the withdraw function can be executed only by the owner.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract mySender{

    address public owner;

    constructor() public payable{
        owner = msg.sender;        
    }

    function multyTx(address[100] addrs, uint[100] values) public {
        require(msg.sender==owner);
        for(uint256 i=0;i<addrs.length;i++){
            addrs[i].transfer(values[i]);
        }
    }

    // In case you change your mind, this will get your ether back to your account
    function withdraw() public {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

    function () public payable{}   
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: if this solved your problem accept the answer so that people know this has been solved.